# Are short trips to Israel allowed?

Tags: halacha, eretz-yisrael, travel

May one visit Israel for a short period of time with no intention of staying?

Comment: Can you explain why you think they may or may not be prohibited? (Do so by [edit]ing, not by commenting.)

Comment: I believe the Lubavitcher Rebbe was under the impression they were, which was one of his reasons for not going to Israel.  (Of course, Rambam did visit and leave, so I'm not sure where the Rebbe got this from)

Comment: @eliyahu-g: I've heard that before, but I'm not sure if it is correct. The Previous Rebbe visited Israel, and, at least according to here - http://www.collive.com/show_news.rtx?id=21641 - , plans were made for the 7th Rebbe to visit Israel with his Father-In-Law, which never worked out.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11067/is-one-allowed-to-conditionally-make-aliyah

Answer (score 1):

Rambam Hilchos Melachim 5:9 based on Mesechtas Avoda Zara 13a says that one may never leave Eretz Yisrael. However the Gemara allows one to leave for various reasons, such as learning Torah, marriage, and business. Thus it would follow that one who has his business, wife, his learning set up outside Eretz Yisrael should be allowed to leave Eretz Yisrael after a visit.

Comment: Yup, Rambam said not to leave E"Y, not to live in Egypt... He wrote that after leaving E"Y for Egypt.