# going to israel on vacation

Tags: chabad, israel

Why didn't the Lubavitcher Rebbe travel to Israel?

When someone asked him, he said that if he went to Israel, according to halacha, he couldn't come back to NYC.

So, is it forbiden to go on vacation in Israel and to come back to golus?

Comment: Prohibition or not, why would anyone voluntarily be in galus without a really good reason???

Comment: Your first 2 lines are difficult to understand. I assume by, "Why did the Lubavither Rebbe couldn't go to Israel?. ", you meant "Why couldn't the Lubavitcher Rebbe  go to Israel?" But I do not understand what you meant by "Only for some day."

Comment: You ask a question which you answer in the next line? Are you asking whether this is an authentic answer? And if your question on the Rebbe or on vacation in Israel? Or both?

Comment: I remember reading that he didn't go to Israel because he didn't believe the Jews there would be as receptive to his message as those outside.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok sorry I'm French I meant like not for a long time juste come to visit and see eretz hakodesh

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi yes he said it's because he had a mission but leave the united states for a few days to come and see eretz hakodesh is this a halachic problem

Answer (score 2):

> when someone asked him he said that if he go to israel according to halacha he couldn't come back to NYC so is it forbiden to go on vacation in israel and to come back to golus?

The Rebbe based this on a Rambam. The Rambam [(Mishneh Torah, Laws of Kings 5:9)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.5.9?lang=bi) writes:

> It is always prohibited to go from the land of Israel to outside of the land, except to study Torah or to marry a woman or to save (possessions) from non-Jews, and [then] to return to the land.

But this was not the main reason why the Rebbe never visited Eretz Yisrael. There are many encounters with the Rebbe, in which the exact same question is asked.

In 1991, a businessman called Yosef Yakir asked the Rebbe the question of why he never visited Eretz Yisrael. The Rebbe responded to him [saying](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4046155/jewish/Why-Didnt-the-Rebbe-Ever-Visit-Israel.htm):

> If you would write to me a halachic responsa that according to Jewish law, I would be permitted to afterward return to the United States, not to abandon the Jews here, then I would evaluate the validity of the argument to see if it is indeed a proper conclusion according to Jewish law. **But to abandon all the Jews here, more than three million people! And it’s not just the American Jews. Some of the Russian Jews are settling here now in the United States, and when they come here, the ground must be prepared so they can continue in their Judaism. And this will be much more difficult to solve if I am in one place and they are in a different place.**

The Rebbe felt great importance for the place where he lived and where he was able to help people. If he left that place, he would not be able to help people in growing in their Yiddishkeit.

A similair point was [said](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4046155/jewish/Why-Didnt-the-Rebbe-Ever-Visit-Israel.htm) by the Rebbe in 1973 to Moshe Ishon:

> Any chassid who comes to ask about going to live in Israel, who isn't involved in education or in the rabbinate, is advised to go, and we give him our blessing for his move. The problem is for those who have vital roles in the community, and if they leave, everything will crumble. They are compared to ships captains in stormy seas; the captain is always the last to abandon ship. First, he must save the passengers.

There's a Hebrew letter, dating from 1983, titled: [מדוע הרבי לא נסע לארץ ישראל](https://he.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/395572) - Why didn't the Rebbe visit Yisrael. In that letter, translated [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4046155/jewish/Why-Didnt-the-Rebbe-Ever-Visit-Israel.htm), the Rebbe says:

> I am using the expression “the front” advisedly. You surely know what
> is happening around you—the very same thing that is happening wherever
> Jews live, especially where they are a small minority—in terms of
> alienation from Yiddishkeit, loss of Jewish identity, intermarriage
> and outright assimilation. **It is the duty of every Jew to do his or
> her very utmost to combat the forces that are threatening the very
> foundations of our people—first and foremost where he finds them in his
> immediate surroundings.** (emphasis mine)

**first and foremost where he finds them in his immediate surroundings -** this is the main point.

With regard to your question whether going on vacation to Eretz Yisrael is halachically permitted, see [this thorough answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/92791/27180).

Comment: You should probably begin your answer by pointing out that the Rebbe’s Father-in-Law, the previous Rebbe did in fact make a trip to Israel as a part of his trip to the United States in 1929. The Rebbe used this example to explain the rest of the subject.

Comment: I've seen an article saying that the Frierdiker Rebbe wanted to pray at the grave of some big tzadikkim, but since he left/fled Russia, wasn't able to do so. So he wanted to go to EY with the Rebbe. I think this was in the 30's. I don't know what the reason was why the Rebbe did not go with the Frierdiker Rebbe.

Comment: That was the year that Rebbe and his wife got married. They were living in Berlin and had been given specific responsibilities there by the previous Rebbe. The Rebbe may have been attending the Hildesheimer School at that point and may not have been free to travel abroad. The previous Rebbe was living in Riga, Poland at that point. As things became more difficult as the Holocaust approached, movement around Europe probably became more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But that does not answer why I must have began my answer with the journey of the Frierdiker Rebbe to EY.

Comment: Based on the question from the OP (L770), they are assuming the Rebbe said it is prohibited to visit Israel and return back to “outside the land of Israel”. By giving the example of the previous Rebbe doing precisely that, it is clear, even by a Chabad Rebbe, that this is not prohibited behavior. The balance of your question is very good, especially the last link.

Comment: Ah I understand. Yes, that was the intent of my answer. Thx for the kind words!

Comment: @YaacovDeane one more reason
the rabbi by bringing back the halachic position of the rambam somehow says that the trip of the previous rabbi was forbidden
and the question was that by following the rambam is it assur to visit yisroel and come back to golus

Comment: By following the Rambam, yes. But, see the answer linked at the bottom!

Comment: @L770 You don’t understand what the Rebbe said and certainly don’t understand the relationship between the Rebbe and his father-in-law. He often described himself literally as his father-in-law. Completely nullified to him to the extent that there was no separation between them at all. He never said the trip by the previous Rebbe to Israel was in any way prohibited.

Comment: @L770 does my answer in any way help you? If so, please consider upvoting and checking it. If not, please let me know. Yor question is a bit unclear to be honest. The Rebbe often quoted the Rambam I included, but, as Yaacod Deane said, he never said that his father-in law was "wrong" in going to EY. The Rebbe felt great importance in staying in Brooklyn, because there were the people that needed him. See my answer.